# How to change the font-size of a popup-menue (MFC, VC6)

Tags: mfc, menu, visual-c++-6, ownerdrawn

I wonder if there is a quick and easy way to change the height of a PopupMenu (i.e. so that each line in the menu has an increased vertical size), and also change the font size to use a bigger font.

Do you have any code samples that can do that? Unfortunately, CMenu does not have an appropriate member to set the font size, or am I missing something? I know there are plenty of samples for ownderdrawn menus out there, which are all overdoing for my purposes. All I want to do is increase the size if the menu items.

Besides, my Menu has no mainwindow, it's just a popupmenu (CMenu::CreatePopupMenu). Most samples seem to require a mainwindow, however.

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible by creating owner-draw menus. To learn about that I suggest readings such as the followings:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647558%28VS.85%29.aspx#_win32_Creating_Owner_Drawn_Menu_Items
- http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/controls/menu/article.php/c3721

Comment: Thanks, but there is one thing that I still do not understand: My menu is created using CreatePopupMenu, and it does not belong to a Main window. However, MFC always calls the MeasureItem overridable for my mainwindow, which has a CMenu member, which is null, because the menu is not part of my mainwindow. How can I achieve that the MeasureItem method of my subclassed menu is called directly, instead of the mainwindows Measureitem function?

Comment: Read the documentation! The HWND that you specify in TrackPopupMenuEx() receives the WM_MEASUREITEM messages.